# Why is notepad++ intending with double tab?

Tags: notepad++

I just noticed that everytime when i copy some text from netbeans to notepad++ and then copy&paste it back to netbeans, everything is intended with double tabs.

**Original**

```
$.ajax
(
    "ajax.php",
    {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        ...
```

**After Pasting from Notepad++ to Netbeans**

```
$.ajax
(
        "ajax.php",
        {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                ...
```

Is there a setting in notepad++ which allows me to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ tabs are at 4 character boundaries, by default. But they are tab characters. See menu => **Settings** => **Tab settings**. Many other programs take tabs to be at 8 character boundaries.

You can see the tab characters by enabling menu => **View** => **Show symbol** => **Show white space and tab**.